# How to change the directory where Eshell stores its history

Tags: eshell

There is a directory created (I am assuming) by Eshell in the Emacs folder by the name of, "eshell" containing files "history, lastdir." Is there a way to specify a different path for these files? Say the ".cache" within the Emacs configs folder. I can't seem to find a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Begin by setting `eshell-directory-name`, and then the following variables will use that same directory:

`eshell-last-dir-ring-file-name`

`eshell-history-file-name`

`eshell-aliases-file`

`eshell-login-script`

`eshell-rc-script`

The above-mentioned file-name variables, use the following code-snippet to determine their values:  `(expand-file-name "INSERT_FILE_NAME_HERE" eshell-directory-name)`

Comment: So `(setq eshell-directory-name ".cache")` takes care of them all?

Comment: In the library `esh-mode.el`, there is a definition for `eshell-directory-name`.  The code-snippet is `(locate-user-emacs-file "eshell/" ".eshell/")`.  So by using only `".cache"`, how would Emacs know how to locate the directory `".cache"` since it could be anywhere on the computer?  I would suggest either an absolute path, or a similar approach to that contained within the aforementioned library.

Comment: For most of my custom locations, I like to set the `user-emacs-directory` variable with a forward trailing slash at the end and then use a snippet like this:  `(concat user-emacs-directory ".0.eshell")`  In my setup, the `user-emacs-directory` is an absolute path with a forward trailing slash at the end.  The value of `user-emacs-directory` is programmatically assigned when Emacs loads based upon the operating system.

Comment: I went with `(setq eshell-directory-name (concat user-emacs-directory  ".cache/eshell/"))`, thanks stranger!